# Install app in 32 bits if there are files in 64 bits lib

Tags: android, google-play

Until yesterday I could build my app using a dummy SO file in arm64-v8a called dummy.so, I added as "not compressed" and it installed 32 bits instead of 64.
From today google play only allows me to name my dummy file starting with "lib" but if I name it like that my app will crash even if i add not compressed to that file.
Is there anyway to run in 32 bits using a dummy dll like I did before but using lib as prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to manifest
`android:multiArch="true" android:use32bitAbi="true"`
It will abioverride and install 32 bits libraries.